# How to toggle between links in ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

[image]

Hi, I'm new to ember js. Can someone please help me with my code? I have created this but I don't know how can I give action to each links. When I click on BreakFast, it should only show me 3 search box(BreadType, cheeseType and meatType) only and other should hide. same for Lunch and Drinks. 
I  also created route for menu in router.

--------------/////application.hbs

```
<h1>Welcome!!</h1>
     {{#link-to 'menu'}}BreakFast{{/link-to}}
     {{#link-to 'menu'}}Lunch{{/link-to}}
     {{#link-to 'menu'}}Drinks{{/link-to}}
    {{outlet}}
```

-------------/////menu.hbs

```
<div>
        <p>Hello from BreakFast</p>
        <label>
            Bread Type:{{input value=bread}}
            Cheese Type:{{input value=cheese}}
            Meat Type:{{input value=meat}}
        </label>
    </div>
<div>
    <p>Hello from Lunch</p>
    <label>
        Calories:{{input value=cal}}
        Price:{{input value=price}}
        Veg/Non-veg:
        <select>
            <option>V</option>
            <option>N</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Hello from Drinks</p>
    <label>
        Drink Name:{{input value=name}}
        Price :{{input value=price}}
        Ice: <select><option>Y</option>
                     <option>N</option>
            </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this is to use Ember's router to do most of the work for you.

First we define three nested routes under `application`, corresponding to `breakfast`, `lunch`, and `drinks`:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('breakfast');
  this.route('lunch');
  this.route('drinks');
});
```

Then, we just put the common parts in the `application` template, along with an `{{outlet}}` where nested templates will be rendered into:

```
// application.hbs
<h1>Welcome!!</h1>

{{#link-to 'breakfast'}}BreakFast{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'lunch'}}Lunch{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'drinks'}}Drinks{{/link-to}}

{{outlet}}
```

And finally, you put each menu type in the respective template:

```
// app/templates/breakfast.hbs
<div>
    <p>Hello from BreakFast</p>
    <label>
        Bread Type:{{input value=bread}}
        Cheese Type:{{input value=cheese}}
        Meat Type:{{input value=meat}}
    </label>
```

```
// app/templates/lunch.hbs
<div>
    <p>Hello from Lunch</p>
    <label>
        Calories:{{input value=cal}}
        Price:{{input value=price}}
        Veg/Non-veg:
        <select>
            <option>V</option>
            <option>N</option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

```
// app/templates.breakfast.hbs
<div>
    <p>Hello from Drinks</p>
    <label>
        Drink Name:{{input value=name}}
        Price :{{input value=price}}
        Ice:
        <select>
            <option>Y</option>
            <option>N</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

And now you should only see the menu type you want! Without more information I can't really advise regarding models and data binding the fields to models.
You can also use the `index` route that Ember automatically creates for you to provide more template for when you visit `/`  in your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for reply. Actually i did this way but i am trying to use single route, single template,controller something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I created [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5415b067cbc8a6f7e72925bc061cb5cf?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ccontrollers.menu.js) to reflect what you requested. queryParam example with single template and controller

I would encourage you to go through official [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com) and play around with [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com). Here is my comment for your [reply](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-set-action/12156/3?u=kumkanillam) in discuss forum,

1. `queryparams : [type],`  change this to  `queryparams : ['type'],`
2. In menu.js controller file, you can't write code like you did, that will throw syntax error while compiling

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    queryparams : [type],

    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
        if('breakfast'){
            BreakFast:true
        }
        else if('lunch'){
            Lunch:true
        }
        else if('drinks'){
            Drinks:true
        }

    });
```

3. In menu.hbs, you have used lots properties in `input` helper but you haven't defined in corresponding controller/model.

---

I saw this question earlier in [discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-set-action/12156).
There are many ways for your use case implementation, but I implemented it for complex requirement it will scale as well.

1.[twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/09acf9d525a5833e68cfee329f954279?numColumns=2&openFiles=routes.menu.js%2Croutes.menu.js&route=%2Fmenus%2F2) for dynamic segment implementation and included dynamic component rendering using component helper.

2. [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5e12161a25944c25b1fb8f419a60f40d?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Croutes.menu.js) for queryaram and included dynamic component rendering using component helper..

I implemented using URL with dynamic segment and dynamic component rendering and component for each menu type. It may be overkill for your requirement but this will give you the better idea.

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'none',
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  //introducing dynamic segment for men types
  this.route('menu',{path: 'menus/:menu_id'});
});

export default Router;
```

**routes/menu.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { isEqual } = Ember;
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){    
    //usually we will request data from server through ember-data or ajax call
    var data = '';      
    if(params.menu_id === '1'){
      data = { bread:' bread name',cheese:'cheese name',meat:'meat name '};
    } else if(params.menu_id === '2'){
      data = { cal:'200',price:'20'};
    }    
    data.menu_id = params.menu_id;    
    return data;
  }
});
```

**controllers/menu.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const {computed} = Ember;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  menuNameComponent: computed('model.menu_id',function(){    
    return this.get('model.menu_id') === '1' ? "menu-breakfast" : "menu-lunch";
  })
});
```

**application.hbs**

```
<h1>Welcome!!</h1>
     {{#link-to 'menu' '1'}}BreakFast{{/link-to}}
     {{#link-to 'menu' 2}}Lunch{{/link-to}}     
 {{outlet}}
```

**menu.hbs**

```
<!-- component helper will dynamically load the specified component -->
{{component menuNameComponent}}
{{outlet}}
```

**templates/components/menu-breakfast.hbs** like this implement it for all the menu type.

```
<div>
        <p>Hello from BreakFast</p>
        <label>
            Bread Type:{{input value=bread}}
            Cheese Type:{{input value=cheese}}
            Meat Type:{{input value=meat}}
        </label>
    </div>
{{yield}}
```

**templates/components/menu-lunch.hbs**

```
<div>
    <p>Hello from Drinks</p>
    <label>
        Drink Name:{{input value=name}}
        Price :{{input value=price}}
        Ice: <select><option>Y</option>
                    <option>N</option>
            </select>
    </label>
</div>
{{yield}}
```

Comment: I won't argue with comments for a downvote. I will learn from it. Most of the downvote I got,  comes with no reason that makes me sad. so please please provide your thought on my answer before downvoting....Maybe this is not the right answer if OP wants to implement it only for 3 routes. I think so.

Comment: thanks kumkanillam. i like your answer too but i want to use single route, may be queryparams is good idea but still searching on it.

Comment: @tomberry I updated one more [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5e12161a25944c25b1fb8f419a60f40d?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Croutes.menu.js) for to use queryParam . Again dynamic component part  may be overkill for your requirement

Comment: can you please check that discussion forum? i have posted my code and my be you can get more idea about my question.

Comment: Created one more twiddle to address your concern.

Comment: thanks you so much kumkanillam :) actually i have just started learning ember and java script. i will sure go through ember guide. if have any suggestion for (beginner)me then please let me know what is the best approach to learn ember js.